# (yii2) error 404 page not found

Tags: php, yii2

This is my **SiteController**

```
 public function actionIndex(){

        $data['book']=[
            ['id'=>1]
            ['id'=>2]
            ['id'=>3]
        ];
        return $this->render('index',$data);
    }
    public function actionView($id){
        $data['id']=$id;
        return $this->render('view',$data);
    }
```

A simple **index.php** file

```
<?php foreach ($book as $bok){ $id =$bok['id']?>
        <a href="index.php?r=site%2Fview?id=<?=$id?>">Views</a>
<?php } ?>
```

and **view.php**

```
<?= $id?>
```

The problem I am having is however that I get an error 404 page not found on the view?id=1 or any other number. I know I have the view.php file in the right place and I do get an error if I try to go to view without an id (the page then tells me that it is missing required parameters: id). I don't know what is causing the problem nor how to solve it. Could you please help?

Comment: Have you enabled pretty url? If so, that requires an .htaccess file.

Comment: No,I did.. not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of a direct formatting of the url you could use urlHelper

```
  use yii\helpers\Url;

 .....

<?php foreach ($book as $bok){ 
        echo "<a href='" . Url::to(['site/view', 'id' => $bok['id'] ]."'>Views</a>";
  } 
?>
```